# Visual Studio: Primary reference could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am upgrading to VS2017 from VS2008, but still need to target .net2.0 due to 3rd party contributions to the project.  A referenced project has been changed to target 2.0, and compiled.  The primary project was also changed to target 2.0, but it errors out at build with this:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "referenced project" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework."

If I look at the properties page for the mscorlib reference in both the referenceed and primary project, it says it is version 2.0.

However, the detailed build log of the referenced project shows this:

1>Target ResolveAssemblyReferences:

1>  Using "ResolveAssemblyReference" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

1>  Task "ResolveAssemblyReference"

1>    TargetFrameworkMoniker:

1>        .NETFramework,Version=2.0

1>    TargetFrameworkMonikerDisplayName:

1>        .NETFramework v2.0

1>    TargetedRuntimeVersion:

1>        v4.0.30319

So, that seems to be where the "indirect dependency" is coming in.  The "TargetedRuntimeVersion" does not match the .NETFramework ones.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Visual Studio needs the 4.0 reference to build. Have you tried just adding the reference?

Comment: The .Net Target Framework Version has been set to 2.0 on the properties page for the main project and for the referenced project.  In the build log for the referenced project you can see that it is intending to use that. But the "Targeted Runtime Version" is staying at 4.0.

Comment: In the <PropertyGroup Label="Globals"> section of the vcxproj file, it does list <TargetFrameworkVersion>2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>.

Comment: I dont have the "Label="Globals"" attribute in my .csproj file. I dont know. it could be this xml-attribute possibly.